# createRef for multiple (dynamic) element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know `React.createRef()` is straight forward, to reference something just declare this in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.inputRef = React.createRef()
}
```

Then in render:

```
render() {
  <input ref={this.inputRef} type="text" />
}
```

I don't know how to work with Refs and the DOM in React version 16.

I have this list and render:

```
<div>{arr.map(person => <div>{person.name}</div>)}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use different names on your refs

```
<input type="text" ref={this.inputField1} />
<input type="text" ref={this.inputField2} />
```

In your constructor you can use createRef for both like so:

```
this.inputField1 = React.createRef();
this.inputField2 = React.createRef();
```

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputField1 = React.createRef();
    this.inputField2 = React.createRef();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick() {
  this.inputField1.current.value = '1'
    this.inputField2.current.value = '2'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputField1} />
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputField2} />
        
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the number of input, it's array of object coming from elsewhere

Comment: @Hanz I think you should be able to loop trough your array to achieve the same results.

Comment: The question is about to create dynamic ref, not just creating multiple variables assigned to one ref